# Replace Multiple Character in File name with regular expression

Tags: python

I have multiple excel file names that have () and space. For example, "(IN) State Project". How do I use regular expression to remove them and the expected output will be "IN_State_Project"

I used python and tried the following. It didn't work

```
s = "(IN) State Project"
s.replace("^(" "|"("|")")$","_")
```

Syntax error

Answer (score 0):

.replace will only replace substring and won't do regex. What you want here potentially is something like:

```
s.replace(" ", "_").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
```

If you want regular expressions, that's the `re` module:

```
import re
s=re.sub("[()]", "", s)
s=re.sub("[ ]", "_", s)
```